# Problem with displaying right form PHP company user / private user

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem whenever I load my form it displays the wrong form,

I have 2 forms, 1 for company and 1 for a customer,

The company form includes everything which the customer form has and more.
The other way around is that the customer form only shows what customer form should show (excludes extra input fields for company)

Relation_type 1 = private customer
Relation_type 0 = company.

at default my form shows the company form even though relation_type = 1

example of private customer user

[image: customer form which includes company form somehow.]

Example of company user

[image: company form for company user]

````
if ($relation_type == 1) 
  {
    window.onload = function() 
    {
        let private = document.querySelectorAll('.private');

        private.forEach(function (value) {
            value.style.display = "";
        })
        company.forEach(function(value) {
            value.style.display = "none";
        })
    }
  }
    else if ($relation_type == 0)
    {
        window.onload = function() 
      {
        let company = document.querySelectorAll('.company');

        private.forEach(function (value) {
            value.style.display = "none";
        })
        company.forEach(function(value) {
            value.style.display = "";
        })
    }
} 
```document.getElementById('relation_type').addEventListener("change", relationfunction);

    function relationfunction() 
    {
        let value = this.value;
        let company = document.querySelectorAll('.company');
        let private = document.querySelectorAll('.private');

            document.getElementById('relation_type').addEventListener('change', function () {
            let selectBox = document.getElementById('relation_type');
            let option = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex];
            console.log(option.value);
            if (option.value == 0) 
            {
                console.log('value is 0');
                private.forEach(function (value) {
                    value.style.display = "none";
                })
                company.forEach(function (value) {
                    value.style.display = "";
                })
            }             
            else if (option.value == 1)
             {
                private.forEach(function (value) { 
                    value.style.display = "";
                })
                company.forEach(function(value) {
                    value.style.display = "none";
                })
            }
         }) 
    }
````

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="relations/editaction.php" method="post">

                <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" onchange="relationfunction()" name="relation_type" id="relation_type">
                </option>
                    <option value="0" <?php echo ($relation_type == 0)?"selected":""; ?>>Organisatie</option>
                    <option value="1" <?php echo ($relation_type == 1)?"selected":""; ?>>Privaat</option>
                </select>
                
                <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group form-row company">
                            <div class="name">Bedrijfsnaam</div>
                            <input class="input--style-5" type="text" name="company_name" value="" placeholder="Company name">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group form-row company">
                            <div class="name">KVK-nummer</div>
                            <input class="input--style-5" type="text" name="chamber_of_commerce" value="" placeholder="COC-Number"> 
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group form-row row">
                            <div class="col"> 
                                <div class="name">Voornaam</div>
                                <input class="input--style-5" type="text" name="firstname" value="" placeholder="First Name">
                            </div>
```

Comment: `if ($relation_type == 1)` – is that supposed to be JavaScript, `$relation_type` is a JS variable here? If so, where does that get its initial value from?

Comment: Ive changed it to if (<?php echo $relation_type?>  == 1)  still does not work

Comment: That makes even less sense than before. I asked you an explicit question for clarification, so please try and answer that first of all.

Comment: if i say that i have changed it to (<?php echo $relation_type?> == 1) then you should know that i meant that $relation_type is a php variable not JS

Comment: Yes, of course, but that does still not explain where that variable is supposed to have gotten any value from to begin with. _“even though relation_type = 1”_ - have you _verified_ that’s what the variable contained at that point, or is that just your _assumption_?

Comment: i have verified it yes sorry I should've clarified.

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? You do `let private = document.querySelectorAll('.private');`, and then `private.forEach(…)`, okay so far - but then `company.forEach(…)` after that, but where is `company` supposed to come from in that position? And in the else branch it is the other way around, there you create `company`, but not `private`, but still try to to `private.forEach(…)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it

```
if (<?php echo $relation_type?>  == 1) 
  {

    window.onload = function() 
    {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("company");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
  }
    else if (<?php echo $relation_type?>  == 0)
    {
        window.onload = function() 
      {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("company");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing php and js in the wrong way. If you want to echo different js based on a PHP condition you should do:

```
<?php if ($relation_type == 1) { ?>
    window.onload = function() 
    {
        let private = document.querySelectorAll('.private');

        private.forEach(function (value) {
            value.style.display = "";
        })
        company.forEach(function(value) {
            value.style.display = "none";
        })
    }
  <?php }else if ($relation_type == 0){ ?>
        window.onload = function() 
      {
        let company = document.querySelectorAll('.company');

        private.forEach(function (value) {
            value.style.display = "none";
        })
        company.forEach(function(value) {
            value.style.display = "";
        })
    }  //this is probably missing in js
   <?php } ?>
```